# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2, servermanager

When trying to bind a cert to IIS im getting error "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated" when committing the changes. I did notice the new cert im trying to bind says the Private Key is NOT exportable. Maybe thats why. Any ideas how to solve this error?

**Code**

```
private void Run(){
        
        dynamic certificates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(api.GetCertificates(_url_base, _username, _password));


        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

         store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

         X509Certificate2 renewedCert = X509Certificate2("c:\\fakeapppreview.gov.crt");

         X509Certificate2 tempCert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(renewedCert.ExportCertificatePem(), store.Certificates[0].GetRSAPrivateKey().ExportRSAPrivateKeyPem());

         store.Add(tempCert);
         var _serverManager = new ServerManager();
         var site = _serverManager.Sites["apppreview"];

         site.Bindings.Clear();
         
         var binding = site.Bindings.Add("*:443:" + site.Name + ".gov", renewedCert.GetCertHash(), store.Name, SslFlags.Sni);
         
         binding.Protocol = "https";
         binding.CertificateHash = tempCert.GetCertHash();
         binding.CertificateStoreName = _serverManager.Sites["riskstaging"].Bindings[0].CertificateStoreName;
         binding.SetAttributeValue("certificateHash", tempCert.GetCertHashString());
         binding.SetAttributeValue("certificateStoreName", binding.CertificateStoreName);
 
         site.ServerAutoStart = true;
         _serverManager.CommitChanges();
         store.Close();
        
}
```

Comment: What is `a` in your code?

Comment: @LexLi updated my code example

Comment: Then what is that crt file? If it is a certificate without private key, then this code is doomed to fail as HTTPS binding cannot be created that way. Read this to learn more https://halfblood.pro/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38

Comment: This may be a permissions issue, please run task scheduler as an administrator.

Comment: @LexLi Ive added the private key now but still get the same error on CommitChanges()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pretty straight forward. All i had to do was use the CopyWithPrivateKey() method to import the private key once I did that adding the binding worked smoothly with everything else.

```
private void Run(){
        
        dynamic certificates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(api.GetCertificates(_url_base, _username, _password));


        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

         store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

         X509Certificate2 renewedCert = X509Certificate2("c:\\fakeapppreview.gov.crt");

         X509Certificate2 tempCert = renewedCert.CopyWithPrivateKey(store.Certificates[0].GetRSAPrivateKey());

         store.Add(tempCert);
         var _serverManager = new ServerManager();
         var site = _serverManager.Sites["apppreview"];

         site.Bindings.Clear();
         _serverManager.CommitChanges();

         _serverManager = new ServerManager();
         site = _serverManager.Sites["apppreview"];
         
         var binding = site.Bindings.Add("*:443:" + site.Name + ".gov", renewedCert.GetCertHash(), store.Name, SslFlags.Sni);
         
         binding.Protocol = "https";
         binding.CertificateHash = tempCert.GetCertHash();
         binding.CertificateStoreName = _serverManager.Sites["apppreview"].Bindings[0].CertificateStoreName;
         binding.SetAttributeValue("certificateHash", tempCert.GetCertHashString());
         binding.SetAttributeValue("certificateStoreName", binding.CertificateStoreName);
 
         _serverManager.CommitChanges();
         store.Close();
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

**Open up certificates in MMC**

Step 1: Open up a Run window and type "mmc"

Step 2: Click File > Add/Remove Snap-In

Step 3: Add > Certificates, Click OK

Step 4: Choose "Computer Account," then "Local Computer," and proceed.

Step 5: Hit OK

**Export Certificate in MMC**

Step 1: Open "Certificates"

Step 2: Open the folder where your certificate is stored.

Step 3: Right Click on Certificate, All Tasks, Export

Step 4: Export to the server Desktop

Now you should be able to re-import your certificate into IIS (or just into MMC) without issue. Restart IIS, and  Note: You may have to reimport as "Complete certificate renewal," depending on your certificate.

If that didn’t work, please check if there is an expired certificate.

Comment: When exporting the certificate in MMC it doesnt allow me to select "Yes, export the private key". The Note says "The associated private key is marked as not exportable. Only the certificate can be exported". The certificate is valid until Nov 2025. Maybe its the way I am importing the private key. I used the command: certutil -repairstore My "SerialNumber"